# PDF Box flatten PDF causes weird spacing

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, flatten-pdf

I'm having an issue with PDF box flattening a PDF generated by Adobe Acrobat DC.

The Adobe Acrobat text field I created is absolutely the default text field.

In my example below, I have a `PatientName` field with the text value `"Douglas McDouggelman"`.

When I flatten the PDF, here's what it looks like:

[image: Shows a weird looking spacing]

Anyone know what's up with this bizarre spacing?

It appears that the space + next character are combined. This is what it looks like when you try to select that character.

[image]

Code:

```
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFormInputStream)) {
  PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();

  PDAcroForm acroForm = catalog.getAcroForm();

  acroForm.getField("PatientName").setValue("Douglas McDouggelman");
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  if (flattenPdfs) {                    
      acroForm.flatten();
  }
  document.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
}
```

Comment: Please share the pdf form.

Comment: Can't send it. security blah blah blah. Can't even make a sample one and upload it due to my local security rules. and I can't make it from an unsecured computer because I do not have adobe acrobat DC on that environment. i'll try to find a way.

Comment: You can download a 30 day trial of adobe acrobat on "that environment" .... (https://acrobat.adobe.com/ua/en/free-trial-download.html)

Comment: Another thing to try: Assuming that it is a PDTextField, please cast and do txtfield.getDefaultAppearance() and output that one. Lets say that the font name is F5 (as in "/F5 12 Tf"). Remember that name and visit  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4233 and see the code lines to replace a font in the default resources.

Comment: `/Helv 0 Tf 0 g`

Comment: Then try to replace that one with the Arial font, which is very similar - just to see what happens. But it is weird, usually /Helv is a standard 14 font and shouldn't make troubles.

Comment: ok that did not work at all but it gave me the idea that i got it to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized this PDF was from some other group who made it and who knows what they did. So I found the source word document, repeated the creation of the form from Adobe DC, added the fields back to the document, then it was totally fine.

PDF box was *not* the problem... it was some unknown incorrect step that the person who originally prepared the pdf did.